# Rails: change the contents of view when click the different link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to change the contents of view when click the different link?

I have two links.

```
<%= link_to "Add event", xxx_path %>
<%= link_to "Add place", xxx_path %>
```

I'd like to display `<%= f.text_field :detail %>` on the view of xxx_path when I click `Add event`, and not to display it when I click `Add place`.

It would be appreciated if you could give me advice.

Comment: Please provide more context around your question as I can think of multiple ways to answer your question. Do you want the user to go to different views via a page refresh or to update in place?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @margo. Although I want the user to go to the same view, I'd like to change the contents of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass additional information along with a GET request you would use query parameters.

example:

```
/cities?near=london
/users/1/orders?status=pending
```

You can pass any hash keys with path/url helpers to generate a path/url with any arbitrary query attached.

```
cities_path(near: 'london')
user_orders_path(user_id: current_user.to_param, status: 'pending')
```

However your example makes very little sense as Event and Place most likely are different resources and should have their own routes and controllers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @max. It works! I pass the parameter and then add `if` clause to change the contents.